# SQL Count to return 0

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I want to search all active records of one table and look for their respective data in a second table and have a count that returns 0 if nothing is found

here is my example.

```
SELECT employee.id, count(jobs.id)
FROM employee LEFT OUTER JOIN jobs ON employee.id = jobs.employee_id
where employee.state ='active' and jobs.startdatetime >= date(now())
group by employee.id
```

If I run w/o the startdatetime range it will return the right amount of rows
If I add the startdatetime range all the employees with no jobs get dropped

Comment: move `and jobs.startdatetime >= date(now())` to the join condition instead

Comment: The problem is jobs.startdatetime >= date(now()) is negating the left join making it an inner.  All records in employee that have no record in jobs are being eliminated because if NULL, it evaluates to false.  Moving the criteria to the JOIN as an `and` condition on the join allows the system to return null records, and count them as 0 in the select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already commented, move the condition `jobs.startdatetime >= date(now())` to your `JOIN` clause as join condition rather like

```
SELECT employee.id, 
count(jobs.id) as job_count
FROM employee 
LEFT OUTER JOIN jobs ON employee.id = jobs.employee_id
AND jobs.startdatetime >= date(now())
where employee.state ='active'
group by employee.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
and (jobs.startdatetime >= date(now()) or jobs.startdatetime is null)
```

and it will work

Comment: The tags make it appear that a number of database engines are being targeted.  Some explanation of the proposed "is null" syntax for each platform would improve this answer.